# Select multiple items with ngDraggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working at something similar to google drive and I am using ngSelectable to select one or more items(from ng-repeat) and ngDraggable to drag and drop files(or folders) in folders.

Selection is working like it should, I don't have any problem with it. ngDraggable is working, but I don't know how to drag multiple selected items. It's working only for one item.
I have something like this on a folder:

```
 ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropFolderOrDocument($data,folder)"
 ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="folder" data-allow-transform="true"
```

I don't know if ngDraggable has something for drag multiple selection, I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!